# django form doesn't display labels

Tags: django

I'm new in django. I try to create a simple form based on the model.
Imputs are displayed fine but i have problem with the labels.They don't appears on the page.
I can't figure out where is my mistake. For my it should be working fine.
Any idea what's is wrong here?

```
class RecForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rec
        fields = ['name', 'kind',]
        labels = {
            'name': 'Here put your name',
        }
```

home.html

```
<form action="addrec" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{% for i in form %}
 {{ i }}
    <br><br>
{% endfor %}
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does your form look like in the template? It seems to me that the problem might be there; your form class looks okay.

Comment: This is how it looks in template.

Comment: try this ``{{i.label}}``

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Here is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rendering the field in your template as `{{ i }}`, with `i` being an instance of a [`BoundField` (code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.2/django/forms/boundfield.py#L14). `BoundField.__str__` calls [`widget.render` (code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.2/django/forms/widgets.py#L277) and returns the output. `widget.render` renders the value of of the widget's template (see widget templates here https://github.com/django/django/tree/4.0.2/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets). None of these templates include the label tag.

To render the label tag your should call [`{{ i.label_tag }}` (code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.2/django/forms/boundfield.py#L148), which will render the tag with all attributes Django knows about. Extra attributes may require adjustments.